# Assigning the output of a SQL query to variable

Tags: shell-script, here-document

I am connecting to oracle database and firing a query and assigning the output to variable
But when I echo the value of the variable it doesn't get printed correctly.

```
count=`sqlplus -s $configuser/$configpass@$ORACLE_SID <<END
           set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
           select max(cust_id) from cutomers
           exit;
           END`
           echo $count
```

The query return correct result when fired on database. But "count" variable has incorrect value.

Comment: please check whether the indenting matches your original code, now after I fixed the formatting. (If matches, then it's wrong. You can not indent the here-documents' closing delimiter like that.)

Comment: What is shown in normal mode, and what's the value of count when assigning?

Answer (score 13):

The terminating here-doc word must be the only characters on the line: no indenting allowed. Also, use `$()` instead of backticks -- they are nestable.

```
count=$(sqlplus -s $configuser/$configpass@$ORACLE_SID <<END
       set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
       select max(cust_id) from cutomers
       exit;
END
)
echo $count
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: You can also use tabs with the `<<-END` notation. Not spaces, TABS!

Answer (score 1):

```
OUTPUT=$( ${OracleClientHome}/sqlplus -S user/pass@database <<EOF
set pagesize 0 linesize 32767 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
select a1.id  || '|' ||
       a1.stmt_begin_date  || '|' ||
       a1.stmt_end_date  || '|' ||
       a1.status  || '|' ||
       a1.total_recs 
from acct_stmt_file a1
 where a1.actp_cd = 'HSA'
   and a1.stmt_begin_date =trunc(sysdate);
exit;
EOF
)

echo -e "\n${OUTPUT}"
```

Comment: Why? I think it would be better if you shared your ideas with the community, too, not only this script snippet.

Answer (score -1):

```
count=`sqlplus -s $configuser/$configpass@$ORACLE_SID <<END
           set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
           select max(cust_id) from cutomers;
           exit;
           END`

           echo $count
```

You have to use the semicolon in right place.

Comment: Also, the `END` at the end needs to be flush to the left, with no whitespace in front of it.